# Normalization in Sentiment analysis

Tags: r, normalization, sentiment-analysis

I' m actually working on the sentiment analysis. In order to calculate the sentiment of a set of reviews I calculated the number of positive, negative words for each sentence. I have a list of positive and negative words(AFINN) with a score which range from -5 to +5.
The problem is that the function gives me only the sum between positive and negative words for each review and not the general sentiment of each review.
In order to calculate the general sentiment:

1) normalize with respect to the maximum for each review (I have score from -5 to +5 for each word, I must add algebraically the scores and divide by the number of  sentiment words )

2) average on all reviews

```
function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='none')
{

    scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {
sentence = tolower(sentence)
sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)

sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)

sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')

# sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
words = unlist(word.list)

# compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms
pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)
neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)

# match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)
neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

# and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():
score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)

return(score)

}, pos.words, neg.words, .progress=.progress )
scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
return(scores.df)
}
```

Comment: Does your code even runs? Seems `lapply` function has been misspelled in your code as laply

Comment: Yes it works. I forgot to say the code needs two packages :stringr and plyr